# Print Page ID on Landing page using AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is it possible to pull in the PageID for a landing page and print it on the page (or place it in a hidden form field)?

What about the ID's of any content areas being used on the page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%%_EmailID%%` will display the `PageID` value also located in Properties.

(Not sure about content area ID, never tried that.)

Comment: %%_EmailID%% is what I am looking for. That worked to get the PageID. Thank you! Marked as answered.

Comment: It's a surprising bonus feature!  Pretty sure you could retrieve the IDs of the Content Areas with the AMPScript API functions.  It's way more verbose that a personalization string, obviously.

Comment: Thanks Adam! I may be exploring that in more detail in the future.

Comment: It works for Landing Pages ...can you have any idea for cloud page ID??? Thanks Srinivas

Comment: On a side note - if the landing page was linked to from an email using MicrositeURL, the %%_EmailID%% will then display the ID of the email that it was linked from, not the Landing Page ID.