# How to find the Page ID of the same page where the AMP script is written

Tags: ampscript, cloudpage, landing-page

[Print Page ID on Landing page using AMPscript](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140788/print-page-id-on-landing-page-using-ampscript)

I am in the process of creating a page to store information from customers who come to the landing page. I want to write it as follows, and I have had no issues storing other information in the Data Extension.

```
%%[

set @id = RequestParameter('userid')
set @SysDate = Now(1)
set @timestamp = SystemDateToLocalDate(@SysDate)
set @email = lookup("Customer Master Test","Email","UserId",@id)
set @phone = lookup("Customer Master Test","MobilePhone","UserId",@id)
set @country = lookup("Customer Master Test","Country","UserId",@id)

  
InsertData("Click_dataextension"
,"UserId",@id
,"EventType","Click"
,"ClickDate",@timestamp
,"Email",@email
,"MobilePhone",@phone
,"CountryCode",@country
,"PageID",%%_EmailID%%)

]%%
```

Additionally, I want to store the Page ID, and I tried putting %%_EmailID%% according to the attached post, but it didn't work.
When I created a new page to see how %%_EmailID%% is displayed, it only appears as 0.

[image: Landingpage Edit] -> What I wrote

[image: Preview] -> preview

How can I find the Page ID of the page where the AMP script is written? (the same page)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a Personalization String for it. As a workaround you can use PageURL, then have a DE that hosts the PageURL in one column, and the PageID in another column (all set up manually). Use a LookUp() to return the corresponding PageID for storing. (Or just insert the URL.)

PageURL is covered here: [Get current location with AMPscript or SSJS](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244042/get-current-location-with-ampscript-or-ssjs)